# How to add second assetlink.json for TWA?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I want to create another TWA app for my website.
My current app default url is mydomain.com/page.

I want to create a TWA App for mydomain.com .

I have already added the assetlink.jason in my host of my first app. How can i add the next assetlink of my second app??

Answer (score 0):

You can add another relationship item to your existing `assetlinks.json`, with the package name and SHA-256 fingerprint of the new app.

Example:

```json
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.mydomain.originaapp",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "FA:2A:03:CB:38:9C:F3:BE:28:E3:CA:7F:DA:2E:FA:4F:4A:96:F3:BC:45:2C:08:A2:16:A1:5D:FD:AB:46:BC:9D"
    ]
  }
},{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.mydomain.secondapplication",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "4F:FF:49:FF:C6:1A:22:E3:BB:6F:E6:E1:E6:5B:40:17:55:C0:A9:F9:02:D9:BF:28:38:0B:AE:A7:46:A0:61:8C"
    ]
  }
}]
```

Note that the `package_name` is different between both items. The SHA-256 fingerprints are different in this case, but they could be the same, if both apps are signed with the same key.